# Adding File to a Folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to relocate newly created Google Docs file to a folder within google drive (using Google Apps).

```
var newFile = DocumentApp.create('New File');
var newFileID = Docs.getFileById(newFile);
var newFileRelocated = newFileID.addToFolder(newFolder);
```

And I'm getting "Cannot find method addToFolder(. (Line ...)". What am I doing wrong? They method drops down as an option when I'm writing it and still it cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that your `newFolder` is not what's expected. Is it a `string`? Where you defined it?

Anyway, the parameter expected in `addToFolder` must be a `Folder` object you got using some other method in `DocsList`. e.g. `DocsList.getFolder("/path/to/folder")` or `DocsList.getFolderById("folder-id")` and so on.

There seems to be other "inconsistencies" with your code, I'll paste what I you're trying to do:

```js
var newDoc = DocumentApp.create('New Google Doc');
//a DocumentApp file and a DocsList file are not the same object, although they may point to the same Google Doc
var newFile = DocsList.getFileById(newDoc.getId());
var folder = DocsList.getFolder("/path/to/folder"); //I'm assuming the folder already exists
newFile.addToFolder(folder);
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic of this is not exactly as you tried...

here is a working example :

```
function myFunction() {
var newFile = DocumentApp.create('New File');
var newFileID = newFile.getId()
var newFolder = DocsList.createFolder('test Folder')
DocsList.getFileById(newFileID).addToFolder(newFolder)
}
```

Comment: @Henrique : Ooops, didn't see your answer while I was typing... kind of a repetition from my side again...sorry ;-)

Comment: It's ok Serge. No need to apologize :)

Comment: Glad it helped, please mark Henrique's answer as best answer, he was first :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, I recently dealt with this issue.

I noticed the default location is to store the DocsList.create() file in the root folder (aka My Drive).

This could lead to a real headache if you were doing lots of files.

I added this as the line after the .addToFolder()

```
newFile.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function is a simple google script to pass in an image URL.

```
function fetchImageToDrive_(imageUrl)
 {
 //Fetch image blob
    var imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getBlob();
 //Create image file in drive
    var folder = DocsList.getFolder('test Folder');
    folder.createFile(imageBlob);
 }
```